# Custom v4.master page in SP 2013 is not visible in site master page dropdown in ChangeSiteMasterPage aspx page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage

I have taken the copy of the v4.master [say **mycustomv4.master**] in SP 2013 publishing site collection using SP Designer 2013 and 
applied my own css, images,and controls.Further, uploaded the same in the master page gallery and edit the properties of this custom master and set the content type as `Master Page`and version as `v4`.

Now I set this custom master as default and custom master page using designer.

But this custom master is not available site master page dropdown,when i went to the look n feel section in settings page.
What am doing wrong? Am not comfortable/ don't know "how-to" in doing design manager and new html-master page mechnasim in SP 2013.That's the reason i went with old traditional copy-paste-existing master v4.master approach.

I have published correctly from the masterpage gallery.

Is it not allowed in SP 2013 that, we should not take the copy of the V4.MASTER and deploy and publish and use it as a  custom master page?

Comment: Did you approve after you published?

Comment: yes, I approved and published through master page gallery UI and even i tried it with SP D as well.This is little bit strange! is it something like, this is not allowed in sp 2013?

Comment: You said you "approved and published." You probably got it right, but I just want to make sure I was clear, you have to publish first, and approve second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to set the UI version as 15 or 16 when you edit the properties of the uploaded master page and make sure you publish it.

[image]

Any reason you're still using v4.master and not seattle or oslo master pages?

Comment: I don't know how to work with the new html master page techniques.Thats the reason i went with v4.master approach and i already have some set up ready from my old sp 2010 master page, so I copied the same and trying to set it similar in sp 2013 with changing logo and alternate css.Is this not allowed?

Comment: I think, that compatible UI version field is the only difference.I previously selected 4 instead of 15.Now i am selecting 15 and checking now!Thanks for your reply n time Aveenav.

Comment: Done! Thank you very much @Aveenav, for the lighting reply and your help! Compatible version as 15 and content type as  asp.net master page was the issue!